# Bash shell script stucks on Jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a bash shell script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

    function start() {
    $WL_HOME/common/bin/wlst.sh <<EOF
      connect ("$username","$password","$URL_ADMIN_SERVER")
      start($1,"Server")
    EOF
    }

    function stop() {
    $WL_HOME/common/bin/wlst.sh <<EOF
      connect ("$username","$password","$URL_ADMIN_SERVER")
      shutdown($1,"Server", ignoreSessions='true', force='true')
    EOF
    }
    if [[ $mode == "start" ]]; then
        for server in ${servers%"--"}; do
            echo "<start-stop-server> *************** Start $server managed server ***************"
            start "$server" &
        done;
        elif [[ $mode == "stop" ]]; then
            for server in ${servers%"--"}; do
                echo "<start-stop-server> *************** Stop $server managed server ***************"
                stop "$server" &
            done;
        fi
```

When passing in the command line multiple values as an array and calling multiple times in the for loop the `start "$server" &` in background (using &), Jenkins is stucking. Passing only two values, Jenkins stuck.

If I pass only one value as parameter in Jenkins or running the script manually in the server with multiple values (2, 3 or more) works perfectly.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What you mean by "pass the command line as array"? Linux does not offer the possibility to pass an array as a parameter to a process. You can only pass strings.

Comment: Why would you launch background processes in a CI/CD builder? Use `wait` to make your script wait for those before exiting.

Comment: About "pass the command line as array", means I am passing multiple values like "string1 string2 string3" and internally for the shell script (according the loop) processing like interacting an array

Comment: About background process, I need to stop multiple weblogic servers when passing the servers in the command line argument. Looking not freeze the script, I am starting the function in background